# Error: Cannot find module 'data-service.js'

Tags: javascript, json, dom, webserver

Hello i am using visual studio code to make a web browser and i am adding some JSON data but am stuck at trying to add the data-service.js using "require" to my server.js file

my data-service.js file has no information in it and this is the error i am getting:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'data-service.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Kevin Chan\Desktop\web322-app\server.js:1:74)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

[MY server.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZ1zt.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the path to the module file, even if it's in the same directory as the script you're running.

```
const data service = require ('./data-service.js');
```